# mips how to print numbers from loop

Tags: assembly

Here is what I have

```
      addi $s0, $0, 10

top:  beq $s0, $0, end

      addi $s0, $s0,-1
      addi $v0,$0,1
      addi $a0,$s0,0
      syscall
      j top

end:
```

The output is 9876543210
but  I want the loop start from 10 to 0 
 109876543210

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `$s0` to 11 instead of 10.

Comment: Thank you ,but if i assume the user will input the value ,I mean if i don't know the value of s0 how can I do it

Comment: If the user enters N, and you want to print N down to 0, initialize $s0 to N+1.

Answer (score 1):

move your "counter" to subtract -1 after your syscall. This way you're subtracting your counter after you run the loop.

```
  ...........
  syscall
  addi $s0, $s0,-1
  j top
```

Comment: That will go 10..1, not 10..0.  You could also change the loop branch to a `bge $s0, $zero, top` so it re-enters the loop as long as `$s0` is non-negative, simplifying the loop to only have one branch total.